# Get alpha value of SKSpriteNode's texture at location

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to ask whether there is a way to get the alpha of a SKSpriteNode's texture at a given location.

What I want to do is to check if a mouse click is relly on the sprite's visible texture or just in its frame.

I'm using Swift and SpriteKit, developing for OS X. I found some answers using UIKit, but as I want to develop for OS X, UIKit isn't available.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access texture data in SK. One approach would be to create a bit mask from the image. You can load the image as a CGImage or UIImage and then scan for all non-transparent pixels. From that you should be able to extract positions and compare them to your tap/click location.